# PHP code is not rendered properly on web browser

Tags: 18.04, apache2, php, php-fpm

I've just installed Apache with PHP-FPM based on the following tutorial

[How to Setup Apache with PHP-FPM on Ubuntu 20.04](https://tecadmin.net/setup-apache-php-fpm-ubuntu-20-04/)

```
wolf@linux:~$ dpkg -l apache2 libapache2-mod-fcgid software-properties-common php7.4 php7.4-fpm
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                          Version             Architecture        Description
+++-=============================-===================-===================-===============================================================
ii  apache2                       2.4.29-1ubuntu4.14  amd64               Apache HTTP Server
ii  libapache2-mod-fcgid          1:2.3.9-1           amd64               FastCGI interface module for Apache 2
ii  php7.4                        7.4.12-3+ubuntu18.0 all                 server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
ii  php7.4-fpm                    7.4.12-3+ubuntu18.0 amd64               server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
ii  software-properties-common    0.96.24.32.14       all                 manage the repositories that you install software from (common)
wolf@linux:~$
```

Test PHP with `phpinfo()` function

```
wolf@linux:/var/www/html$ cat info.php 
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
wolf@linux:/var/www/html$
```

The only issue right now is PHP file seems to be processed properly in CLI, but not via web browser.

```
wolf@linux:/var/www/html$ php info.php | head
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 7.4.12

System => Linux 4.15.0-122-generic #124-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 15 13:03:05 UTC 2020 x86_64
Build Date => Oct 31 2020 17:04:09
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/7.4/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d
wolf@linux:/var/www/html$
```

Unfortunately, it's not working on web browser

[image]

php7.4-fpm service is already started

```
wolf@linux:~$ systemctl status php7.4-fpm
● php7.4-fpm.service - The PHP 7.4 FastCGI Process Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php7.4-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-11-02 07:12:15 ; 1min 36s ago
     Docs: man:php-fpm7.4(8)
  Process: 739 ExecStartPost=/usr/lib/php/php-fpm-socket-helper install /run/php/php-fpm.sock /e
 Main PID: 695 (php-fpm7.4)
   Status: "Processes active: 0, idle: 2, Requests: 0, slow: 0, Traffic: 0req/sec"
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 1129)
   CGroup: /system.slice/php7.4-fpm.service
           ├─695 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
           ├─737 php-fpm: pool www
           └─738 php-fpm: pool www

Nov 02 07:12:14 linux systemd[1]: Starting The PHP 7.4 FastCGI Process Manager...
Nov 02 07:12:15 linux systemd[1]: Started The PHP 7.4 FastCGI Process Manager.
```

This is the only things appear on access.log

```
wolf@linux:~$ tail -F /var/log/apache2/access.log

127.0.0.1 - - [02/Nov/2020:07:23:50 ] "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1" 304 180 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36"
```

There is no new log at `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and `/var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log`

What wrong in this case and what should I do to troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 0):

For what you show, the handler is not being executed. So, it is displaying the PHP file as if it was a text file.

Did you create the virtual host entry?

I checked the document you link and something is missing.

They create the config for the site on:
`/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

But a symbolic link to this file should be created in: `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`

Please do:

```
ls -al /etc/apache2/sites-available/
ls -al /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache also needs to be configured to support PHP-FPM (apache2 + php-fpm)

The Apache configuration file `/etc/apache2/conf-available/php7.4-fpm.conf` is created automatically after installing PHP-FPM.

If it's not there, you can also create this file manually.

`/etc/apache2/conf-available/php7.4-fpm.conf`

```
# Redirect to local php-fpm if mod_php is not available
<IfModule !mod_php7.c>
<IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>
    # Enable http authorization headers
    <IfModule setenvif_module>
    SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
    </IfModule>

    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost" # PHP version (php -v command)
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
        # Deny access to raw php sources by default
        # To re-enable it's recommended to enable access to the files
        # only in specific virtual host or directory
        Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>
    # Deny access to files without filename (e.g. '.php')
    <FilesMatch "^\.ph(ar|p|ps|tml)$">
        Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Then, activate the `proxy_fcgi` module:

`sudo a2enmod proxy_fcgi`

Also, activate the configuration file:

`sudo a2enconf php7.4-fpm`

Reference:
https://develike.com/en/articles/configuring-apache-to-support-php-fpm-on-debian-ubuntu